# python + psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at end of input

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm getting this error message

```
 cursor.execute(query, variables)
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at end of input
```

My code

```
data = {
    'country': data['country'][x],
    'year': data['year'][x].astype(float),
    'month': data['month'][x].astype(float)
}
db_connection.execute(
    f"""
    INSERT INTO my_table (country, year, month) VALUES (%(country)s, %(year)s, %(month)s) ON CONFLICT (country, year, month)
    """,
    data,
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a conflict_action in your sql statement. See [https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#:~:text=ON%20CONFLICT%20DO%20NOTHING%20simply,can%20perform%20unique%20index%20inference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#:%7E:text=ON%20CONFLICT%20DO%20NOTHING%20simply,can%20perform%20unique%20index%20inference). for details.

EG You might want `ON CONFLICT (country, year, month) DO NOTHING`